# Finding highest point on displacement map returns bizarre results

Tags: shaders, hlsl

I find the highest point of a displacement map sampled at 9 different UV coordinates that i pass in an array to the shader. Then if the result is more than 0.7 I output a red pixel at every UV coordinate in the array. If it is less than 0.7 I output a green pixel. So, you'd expect all the colors to be either red or green. But bizarrely they're red AND green.

````
uniform float4 _ArrayCoordinatesOfSplats[9];
float4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
{
float4 heightOfDisplacementMapAtOutputPixel = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
bool brushTouchingOutputPixel = false;
float greatestHeightAtSpotLocations = -1;

for (int index = 0; index < 9; index++)
{
    half2 diff = _ArrayCoordinatesOfSplats[index].xy - i.uv;
    half2 scaledDiff = diff * half2(_SizeX, _SizeY);
    if (abs(scaledDiff.x) < 0.5 && abs(scaledDiff.y) < 0.5)
    {
        float heightOfDisplacementMapAtSplatPosition = tex2D(_MainTex, _ArrayCoordinatesOfSplats[index].xy).r;
        if (heightOfDisplacementMapAtSplatPosition > greatestHeightAtSpotLocations)
        {
            greatestHeightAtSpotLocations = heightOfDisplacementMapAtSplatPosition;
        }
        brushTouchingOutputPixel = true;
    }
}
if (brushTouchingOutputPixel)
{
    if (greatestHeightAtSpotLocations < 0.7f)
    {
        return float4(0, 1, 0, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        return float4(1, 0, 0, 1);
    }
}
else
{
    return heightOfDisplacementMapAtOutputPixel;
}
}
```
````